# How can I add "space" to the output without wrapping the text (React, typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, syntax

I want to display the current time as "hh:mm Uhr" in my table column.
It works well until I add a space within the code between the hh:mm and the word 'Uhr'. If I do so, the text will wrap.
It seems to me that the space character functions as enter within the code.
Does anyone have a solution for me that might work?

Here is my code:

```
let currentTime = `${hours.toString().length === 1 ? `0${hours}` : hours}:${minutes.toString().length === 1 ? `0${minutes}` : minutes} Uhr`;
```

The piece of code I mean is in the end: **minutes} Uhr`;**

The output if I leave out space:

```
09:33Uhr
```

The output if I put space there:

```
09:33
Uhr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a different approach. There is a plugin called dayjs. It makes using time and editing it a lot easier.

This is my code now:

```
function processDate(date: string) {
    const parsedDate = dayjs(date).locale("de"); {/*Enter your country letters here to use your local time*/}
    return (
        <>
            <div>
                {parsedDate.format('DD MMM YYYY')}  {/Output: *01 Jan 1970*/}
            </div>
            <div>
                {parsedDate.format('HH:mm')} h {/Output: *00:00 h*/}
            </div>
            <div>
                {parsedDate.from(dayjs())} {/*takes the difference from then to now*/}
            </div>
        </>
    )
    /*format('DD MMM YYYY, HH:mm [h]');*/
```

You have to install dayjs to use it.
Also, there is a nice documentation about it:
https://github.com/iamkun/dayjs/blob/dev/docs/en/API-reference.md#displaying

Answer (score 0):

You can try by adding `&nbsp;`

So your code will be:
let currentTime = `${hours.toString().length === 1 ?` 0${hours}`: hours}:${minutes.toString().length === 1 ?`0${minutes} `: minutes}&nbsp;Uhr`;

Comment: When I add &nbsp; it is displayed in my table like "09:48&nbsp;Uhr. Using your whole code line doesn't work in my code for a few reasons which I have no solutions for.